# A story where a disease causes children to stop aging

Tags: story-identification

What I remember:
There is a disease that causes children to stop developing physically and mentally. The main character is a youngish child that has been that way for many years, and I think is working as a detective. She(?) is envious of the ones that were frozen in their teens because at least they went through puberty.

And the ones that were frozen as babies get cybernetic enhancements to allow them to function in society. The main character consults one because of the scary amount of computing power it has for hacking and the like.

**EDIT:**
I don't remember much more. I think it was a short(er) story. I think it was 10-15 years ago that I read it, though it could be as few as 7 years.
I remember the main character being very envious of the older kids because they had matured enough to have physical relationships.
I remember the main character and others being scared of the cyborg baby because of the power it had, and that they knew it was in the area because it was disrupting the power grid around it.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?

Comment: ^_^ I think they're past their first badge...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, oops, it's an automatic comment, and falling asleep on a Eurostar made me miss that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is ["Start the Clock"](http://www.benjaminrosenbaum.com/stories/start.the.clock.html) by Benjamin Rosenblum.

> I put my hands in my pants pockets and picked at the lint. "So this is pretty much all Nines?"
>
> The Thirtysomething Lady frowned. "Ma'am, I'm afraid the Anti-Redlining Act of 2035 --"
>
> "Uh-huh, race, gender, **aetial age, chronological age,** stimulative preference or national origin -- I know the law. But who else wants to live in Pirateland, right?"

...

> Frankly, we were excited. This move was what our Pack needed -- the four of us, at least, were sure of it. We were all tired of living in the ghetto -- we were in three twentieth-century townhouses in Billings, in an "age-mixed" area full of marauding Thirteens and Fourteens and Fifteens. **Talk about a people damned by CDAS -- when the virus hit them, it had stuck their pituitaries and thyroids like throttles jammed open. It wasn't just the giantism and health problems caused by a thirty-year overdose on growth hormones, testosterone, estrogen, and androgen.** They suffered more from their social problems -- criminality, violence, orgies, jealousy -- and their endless self-pity.

Comment: Thats the one! Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Found the Escape Pod episode where I originally heard it: http://escapepod.org/2007/03/29/ep099-start-the-clock/